# Angular JS ng-repeat not working with Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple list

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="spiel in spielListe">Do something</li>
</ul>
```

And a controller (which is perfectly connected)

```
$scope.spielListe = [];
```

In addition there is a larger method which pushes some objects to the array in this structure:

```
var spielObjekt = {team1: "Teamname 1", team2: "Teamname 2", court: ""};
$scope.spielListe.push(spielObjekt);
```

In the end the array looks like that:

[image: Chrome view of the Array]

The content of the objects does not really matter, as angular should execute the ng-repeat twice and just show my text twice - but the html page stays empty.

What am I doing wrong? Where could I do a mistake?

**Update**

There seems to be a problem with the .push. I put one Object with the same structure into my array which is recognized in the ng-repeat. But the 2 Objects that are pushed in later are not shown. Problem?

**Update 2**

Thank you for your help - the mistake was, that several elements in the DOM had ng-controller="contentCtrl" inside. Which means the controller got called several times and the objects refreshed - did not understand that

Comment: Could you add a JSFiddle or similar. The situation you describe seems correct and I can't recreate the error you described. https://jsfiddle.net/7MhLd/2312/

Comment: Have you specify the controller with `ng-controller='YourController'` in the body tag for instance ?

Comment: code appears to be fine....are there any errors on console?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/4L9ys7g9 - I Agree it looks massive but the output is simple

Comment: Update: There seems to be a problem with the .push. I put one Object with the same structure into my array which is recognized in the ng-repeat. But the 2 Objects that are pushed in later are not shown. Problem?

Comment: @mstoldt did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 2):

There are some lack of clarity in the data provided. From your question I think you are looking for one of the below cases

> Case 1

If you are expecting your object as `{team1: "Teamname 1", team2: "Teamname 2", court: ""}`, this will print only one time in the output as this is a single object.

Here is the sample for the above situation..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="spiel in spielListe">{{spiel.team1}}</li>
        </ul>
        <button ng-click="addItems()">Add</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.spielListe = [];
            $scope.addItems = function () {

                var spielObjekt = {
                    team1: "Teamname 1",
                    team2: "Teamname 2",
                    court: ""
                };
                $scope.spielListe.push(spielObjekt);
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

> Case 2

But if you still want this three times at your output, you need to modify the JSON structure, like this

```
["Teamname 1", "Teamname 2", ""]
```

and ng-repeat as

```
<li ng-repeat="spiel in spielListe">{{spiel}}</li>
```

or JSON structure as

```
[{TeamName: "Teamname 1"}, {TeamName: "Teamname 2"}, {TeamName: ""}]
```

and ng-repeat as

```
<li ng-repeat="spiel in spielListe">{{spiel.TeamName}}</li>
```

because looping can be done only through an array of objects not through a single object.
 Here is the example of that implementation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="spiel in spielListe">{{spiel}}</li>
        </ul>
        <button ng-click="addItems()">Add</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.spielListe = [];
            $scope.addItems = function () {

                var spielObjekt = [
                    "Teamname 1", "Teamname 2", ""
                ];
                $scope.spielListe = $scope.spielListe.concat(spielObjekt);
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `spielObjekt`  variable is just one object and you pushing one object to an array, so tour `<li>` should print just one time.
So, `spielObjekt`  variable like this..

```
var spielObjekt = [{team1: "Teamname 1"},{team2: "Teamname 2"},{court: ""}];
```

And you dont have use push,just set `spielObjekt`  variable to `$scope.spielListe` .your `<li>` will print 3 times.

```
$scope.spielListe = [];
var spielObjekt = [{team1: "Teamname 1"},{team2: "Teamname 2"},{court: ""}];
$scope.spielListe = spielObjekt;
```

Comment: You don't get the code, I probably explained it poorly. I have several objects of the same structure I need to push inside so it does make sense in my use

Comment: that's not what he want , that is one single object , not different objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1 :** You are passing single object in `$scope.spielListe`. Hence, ng-repeat iterate it only once.

**Case 2 :** If you having `spielObjekt` as array of objects then you have to iterate it to push both the objects in an `$scope.spielListe` array.

**Working Demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
  $scope.spielListe = [];
  var spielObjekt = [
             {team1: "Teamname 1", team2: "Teamname 2", court: ""},
             {team3: "Teamname 3", team4: "Teamname 4", court: ""}
             ];
  
  for (var i in spielObjekt) {
    $scope.spielListe.push(spielObjekt[i]);
  }

  console.log($scope.spielListe);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="spiel in spielListe">Do something</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here, You can see in the code snippet that `$scope.spielListe` is having array of 2 objects and its working fine.